# What is Iran's stance on the UN regulating technology in the field of cyberterrorism?

Tags: united-nations, iran

As of recently, Iran has emerged on the world stage of cyber technology after recent sores over Stuxnet. However, Iran is still behind other world superpowers like Russia and the US.

Essentially, if the UN were to vote on whether or not it should control laws on cyber terrorism, would Iran vote for or against this measure?

Background:
Both Stuxnet and Flame damaged networks other than intended targets.
It is not in the best interest for the United States to curb its own prowess so it might vote no, but looking at how they only have an offensive advantage, not a defensive advantage, it may be beneficial if other nations do rapidly emerge.
Iran raised the second largest cyber army in the world a while back. They both attack and get attacked.

I've done a little research on this and I'm not sure which way Iran would go (Model UN).
Thanks for any and all help, even if it's just an opinion!